# USB hub disconnects from Mac Pro occasionally

Tags: macos, usb, mac-pro

I have a 2013 Mac Pro (cylinder version) running 10.9.2 and I'm using a Monoprice 24-port USB2 hub with it. About once a day for the past few days, the hub has fallen off the USB bus, along with all of the devices connected to it. When this happens, it somehow disables the USB port on the Mac, as connecting other devices to that port doesn't work. Connecting the hub to a different USB port works fine. Restarting the computer fixes everything until it happens again. My memory isn't clear, but I believe this only began happening when I upgraded to 10.9.2.

When the problem occurs, I get error messages in the Console like this:

```
3/5/14 3:16:18.000 PM kernel[0]: USBF:    92321.242    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 3 of Hub at 0x20000000)
3/5/14 3:16:21.000 PM kernel[0]: USBF:    92324.322    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
3/5/14 3:16:22.000 PM kernel[0]: USBF:    92325.175    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 3 of Hub at 0x20000000)
3/5/14 3:16:25.000 PM kernel[0]: USBF:    92328.657    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
3/5/14 3:16:26.000 PM kernel[0]: USBF:    92329.509    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 3 of Hub at 0x20000000)
3/5/14 3:16:27.000 PM kernel[0]: USBF:    92330.361    The IOUSBFamily gave up enumerating a USB device after 10 retries.  (Port 3 of Hub at 0x20000000)
```

These same messages also appear when I plug a new device into the now-dead port.

Any idea what's going on here or how to fix it? "Having trouble enumerating" is unfortunately not very specific, and I've been unable to find any helpful information about what could cause it.

Comment: I must say that MonoPrice quality is very, very low. We purchased Thunderbolt <> VGA adaptors for our faculty which failed after a few weeks. We will no longer purchase their products. The error log above mentions that port 3 on this hub is a culprit. What is plugged into port 3? If you move the device in port 3 to another port, does the hub disconnect and show that new port in the error log? If port 3 still shows an error, or there has never been anything plugged into port 3, perhaps port 3 is the source of error. I recommend Belkin USB hubs - well made and sturdy. (Satisfied Belkin customer)

Comment: My experience with Monoprice has been the opposite. In any case, this particular unit worked fine for months, on this computer and on the one it replaced. Port 3 is the port on the Mac Pro that's the hub is connected to. It varies depending on which port I connect it to, and shows the same error (specifically mentioning port 3) if I plug e.g. my mouse into the dead port after the hub disappears.

Comment: What happens when you plug the hub into another port on the MacPro?

Comment: Connecting the hub to a different USB port makes it work again. However, I've tried two different ports long-term and they both eventually died after a day or so, so the initial problem is not port-specific.

Comment: Something similar happens with one of my pen drives in my mid 2012 13" MBP. I thought that it was a issue with the pen drive.

Comment: This seems like an interesting problem. Have you filed a radar?

Comment: I haven't filed a radar. Unfortunately, I find the revamped web UI intolerable to use, and the odds of getting anything useful out of it are remote.